# How to use nested queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

First is `employee` table, second is `works_with` table
[image]

`emp_id` is foreign key in `works_with` table.

What I want to do is to find first name & last name who has total sales more than 100,000.

For example, in first table, `emp_id` 105 person has 110,000 total sales.

So I want the output to be first name and last name of emp_id 102, 104, 105(whose total sales are more than 100,000).

I tried some nested queries and failed.

Failed code:

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name
FROM employee
WHERE employee.emp_id IN(
    SELECT works_with.emp_id, sum(total_sales)
    FROM works_with
    WHERE works_with.total_sales > 100000
    GROUP BY works_with.emp_id);
```

Comment: Please post sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And show desired output for sample data strongly.

Comment: *whose total sales are more than 100,000* Maybe you mean "the sum of all total_sales for an employee is over 100k"?

Comment: And specify your MySQL version - it is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using `WHERE-IN` you must select only one column in subquery
and use aggregates functions for comparison in the `HAVING` clause they don't work with `WHERE`.

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name
FROM employee
WHERE employee.emp_id IN(
    SELECT works_with.emp_id
    FROM works_with
    GROUP BY works_with.emp_id
    HAVING SUM(total_sales) > 100000
)
```

also you can use `INNER JOIN` to get same result

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name,SUM(total_sales) as total_sales
FROM employee
INNER JOIN works_with ON employee.emp_id = works_with.emp_id
GROUP BY employee.emp_id
HAVING total_sales > 100000
```

Comment: Appreciate it although an insufficient info.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `JOIN` rather than `WHERE-IN`. And you need to test the sum of all total sales, not the individual total sales. You can do that using `HAVING`.

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM employee AS e
JOIN works_with AS w ON e.emp_id = w.emp_id
GROUP BY e.emp_id
HAVING SUM(w.total_sales) > 100000
```